# Unable to load dll when running process with PsExec

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2008, psexec

When i run my app using PsExec (same machine but with user credentials) i receive the following error when trying to load a dll:

Unable to load DLL 'AcWsHost.dll': Exception from HRESULT: 0xE06D7363.

It happen also when the credentials are of the same user (Administrator).

Any idea why it happens or how i can solve it?

Comment: It bombs with an unhandled C++ exception.  Anything is possible, add logging to the code.